# Google app engine login Invalid_client

Tags: google-app-engine

I've setup the tic tac toe [example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=NU_wNR_UUn4#t=1308)  and I'm getting the following error when I try to login to the web tic tac toe. Any suggestions?
[image]

When I click sign-in I get I removed the project ID from the pic after 'origin=' because I didn't want everyone knowing the project-ID:

[image]

Comment: Did you substitute the YOUR-CLIENT-ID with the Client Id for your application from the Google Console?

Comment: In the 'appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-java' eclipse java project that I downloaded there is a 'Ids.java'file, which states to place your web_client_id= 'your client id' and I did place it there. In that same location it has for IOS_CLIENT_ID, ANDROID_CLIENT_ID, and WEB_CLIENT_ID, which I populated. Which client_ID should I input the 'YOUR-CLIENT-ID'? I tried placing the client ID in the 'YOUR-CLIENT-ID" location and it still gave same login error.

Comment: So, did you replace the WEB_CLIENT_ID with your own Client ID ?

Comment: In the google cloud console 'API Access' I generated a client ID for a web application and placed int the code where it states 'YOUR-CLIENT-ID' and it still failed. In fact I placed it in both the 'ids.java' file and the 'render.js' file were it states 'YOUR-CLIENT-ID'

Comment: In regards to the client ID I placed the entire '##############.apps.googleusercontent.com'